# HTML/Javascript && Condition in an If Statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, radio-button

I am sure there is a very simple fix to this and that I am most likely not doing this the most efficient way possible.

I am trying to create an if statement that will check to see if multiple radio buttons are selected in multiple questions. If they are selected, I would like an alert box to pop up with a certain message. There will be many selection combinations possible so I am assuming many if/else statements(?)

The Javascript in question is located at the bottom.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Spigit Input Form</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Spigit Input Form">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Project_File_CSS.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery_spigit.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!--<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="New_File_JS.js"></script>-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selection_storage.js"></script>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="recommendation_logic.js"></script>-->

<!---------------------------------------------------------Operating Company Question----------------------------------->
<form name="operatingCompany">
<h3>What Operating Company Are You Employeed With?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="opco" value="GPC" >GPC</br>
<input type="radio" name="opco" value="APC" >APC</br>
<input type="radio" name="opco" value="MPC" >MPC</br>
<input type="radio" name="opco" value="Gulf" >Gulf</br>
<input type="radio" name="opco" value="SCS" >SCS</br></br>

<input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_opco() />
</form>

<p id="opco_result"> </p></br>


<!---------------------------------------------------------Prototyped Question----------------------------------->
<form name="prototyped">
<h3>Has the innovation been prototyped?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="prototyped" value="Yes" >Yes</br>
<input type="radio" name="prototyped" value="No" >No</br></br>

<input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_prototype() />
</form>

<p id="prototyped_result"> </p></br>

<!--------------------------------------------------------Adopted or Tested Question---------------------------->
<form name="adopted_tested">
<h3>Has the innovation been adobpted or tested?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="adopt" value="Yes" >Yes</br>
<input type="radio" name="adopt" value="No" >No</br></br>

<input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_adopt_test() />
</form>

<p id="adopted_tested_result"> </p></br>

<!------------------------------------------------------Can it make money Question------------------------------->
<form name="makeMoney">
<h3>Is this a product or service that can make money?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="money" value="Yes" >Yes</br>
<input type="radio" name="money" value="No" >No</br></br>

<input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_money() />
</form>

<p id="makeMoney_result"> </p></br>

<!---------------------------------------------------Alabama Power Specific Question----------------------------->
<h3>What is your innovative idea to help Alabama Power improve safety, grow revenue, reduce cost, or increase operational efficiency?</h3>
<textarea id="alabamaPower" rows="8" cols="50">

</textarea> </br></br>

<input type="button" value="Display User Input" onclick=textareacapture() />

<p id="result"> </p></br>

<!------------------------------------------------IT Specific Question------------------------------------------->
<form name="innovativeTechnology">
<h3>Is your innovation an innovative technology or process that boosts the company's productivity or brings additional value from a vendor relationship?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="innovative" value="Yes" >Yes</br>
<input type="radio" name="innovative" value="No" >No</br></br>

<input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_innovative() />
</form>

<p id="innovativeTechnology_result"> </p></br>

<input type="button" value="Submit Form" onclick=get_recommendation() />

<script>
function get_recommendation(){
        if((document.operatingCompany.opco[0,1,2,3,4].checked) && (document.prototyped.prototyped[0,1].checked) && (document.adopted_tested.adopt[0,1].checked))
        {
            alert("Everyday Solutions");
        }       
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, `document.operatingCompany.opco[0,1,2,3,4]` is equivalent to `document.operatingCompany.opco[4]`. This is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), it doesn't automatically map the operation to multiple subscripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use this test to identify whether any radiobutton has been checked:

```
($(":checked").length > 0)
```

You may refine the selector if you are only interested in a subset of the radio buttons or checkboxes on the page.

Comment: This seems to work (or at least gets me closer to my goal):                                                                                 `$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('input[name="opco"]:checked')) {
    alert("It Works");
}
});`               But, there are still issues: (1) The alert box appears on page load (2) The alert box appears even when radio buttons are not checked.          I would like for the Submit Form button to trigger the alert box.

Comment: re 1.), re 2.) In your `if` statement you _must_ test for the `length` property of the jQuery object. This object is constructed regardless whether the selector matches or not. Thus testing for the object always yields a truthy value, thus the alert box is always shown.

Comment: (re 3.) If you wish the submit button to trigger the alert, use the condition in the `if` statement guarding the alert in `getRecommendation`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked at run time what the values are in your variables in the if? Also, currently you are checking that all of them are checked. Do you want to check if some of them are checked?

Also, are you sure you want to use an alert. A modal is really preferable. An alert will block the event loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). See [why do I need 50 reputation to comment, what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) for an explanation.

Comment: @TheOracle He doesn't have enough rep for that.

Comment: If any are checked in the first question and Yes is selected in the second two questions, then I want to output a specific message. Another example: If any are selected in the first question, No is selected in the second two questions, and yes is selected in the fourth question, then I want to display a different output.

Answer (score 0):

> Logical and(&&)

```
if (x>5 && x<10) 
{
    alert("your enter value between range 6 to 9");
}
```

> Here, is javascript code you enter only 6 to 9 between range

Comment: And what about betwwen like `if (5 < x < 10) { ... }`

Comment: Haha,this if condition always run true block,because your condition is logically false means not possible

Answer (score 0):

And what about *betwwen* like ine PHP/C ?

```
if (5 < x < 10) {
    ...
}
```